# Poke a hole in "Pinning"

Tags: discussion, tags

My apologies for not moving on this in some direction. I don't know what that direction should be, so I think I should defer to users who are more regular on the site.

The [pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning) tag does not have a description. I recently used it for classification of a public key pinning question. I'm not sure that's correct based on some of the other questions tagged with [pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning).

Please provide a description for [pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning). (I'm happy to use whatever the site decides; I just need to know what the decision is).

Comment: *Unpin the pinning tag*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it stands I'd say this is a meta tag and deserves absolute burnination.

In order for this tag to be useful it *must* be used with another tag, it is almost never useful on its own.

I'd say you probably need separate tags for whatever kind of pinning you are doing, be it [public-key-pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/public-key-pinning), [desktop-pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-pinning), [taskbar-pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/taskbar-pinning), [chrome-pinned-tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chrome-pinned-tabs), [apt-pinned-versions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apt-pinned-versions) or similar.

Most of the questions with [pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning) I saw at a glance would better off with [taskbar-pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/taskbar-pinning), as they talk about shortcuts or programs that have been pinned to the taskbar in Windows 7 or above.

[pinning](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pinning) itself needs several large needles punched through it though.

Comment: Ah, that's fine by me, too. In that case, let me remove that tag from my question.

Comment: Should I accept the answer? (This is one of those awkward times; I'd like one of the Meta admins to accept it if its the official position of the site).

Comment: @jww personally I'd give it a day or so to see if anyone has another view on the matter but if you would prefer I can open a new question with this as a retag request.

Comment: It's not a meta tag, it's just highly ambiguous.