# Stick it to [pin]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[pin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pin) is undefined, with 35 questions and many meanings:

- Damaged pins on chips, connectors, etc.
- Personal Identification Number
- Connector configurations
- Anchoring an application, folder, etc.
- Deskpins

It's a candidate for cleanup.

There appears to be some commonality with [Poke a hole in "Pinning"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9674/poke-a-hole-in-pinning), which, like the weather, was talked about but not acted on.  Maybe both of these could get the official [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag.

Comment: @BenN: I was wondering how to do that.  Thanks.